# Deleting images from parse using canEditRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am currently coding a small project something similar to instagram using swift(parse). After the user posts an image  it is uploaded to parse and I am retrieving it into a tableview. Since images need to be converted to NSData and to PFFile it is saved as a PFFile. I was trying to delete the file from parse from table view using  `canEditRowAtIndexPath` by      `objectToDelete.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock`.  However from my research I found out that PFFile cannot be deleted from the user and only objects can be deleted. However image files are too big for objects. (I hope I'm right). I would like to know how to make it not show up in the table view after the user does not want to see it or delete the post.

UPDATE

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        println("Commit Editing Style \(editingStyle)")
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> [AnyObject]! {



    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete", handler: {
        (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) in
        println("Triggered delete action \(action) atIndexPath: \(indexPath)")
        return
    })

    return [deleteAction]
}


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {


            var fileName = "uploaded_image.png"
            let applicationID = "appidwritten"
            let masterKey = "masterkeywritten"

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.parse.com/1/files/\(fileName)")!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "DELETE"
            request.setValue(applicationID, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
            request.setValue(masterKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Master-Key")
            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    println(response)
            }).resume()

}


}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a file by `deleteInBackgroundWithBlock`:

> **Why can't I delete a file using the SDK?**
>
> Since files do not have ACLs, their write access cannot be restricted to a specific user. Since leaving files open to deletion by any arbitrary user is not a great security measure, we require that a master key is used to delete a file. Since client SDKs cannot use the master key, you will need to use the REST API.
>
> https://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-delete-a-file

So you should delete a file through the REST API like this:

```
var fileName = ""
let applicationID = ""
let masterKey = ""

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.parse.com/1/files/\(fileName)")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "DELETE"
request.setValue(applicationID, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
request.setValue(masterKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Master-Key")
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    println(response)
}).resume()
```

The name of the file must be the name in the response of the upload operation, rather than the original filename.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer! I never knew that you can use swift in REST API.  Does that mean that I can put the above code in `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  if editingStyle == .Delete {`  Since I don't see anything happening. I have filled the file name and app id and master key correctly.

Comment: I think putting this code in a helper class is a better way, then you call the helper class from almost anywhere in your project.

Comment: no I can't even slide to delete. I have updated my code.